# Drawing order in XNA

Tags: xna, c#

When manually setting the drawing order of game components by setting

```
int DrawableGameComponent.DrawOrder
```

can one use any integer numbers as long an order is defined like

- component1 => drawing order: 2
- component2 => drawing order: 5
- component3 => drawing order: 10
- component4 => drawing order: 323

or do these integers have to be consecutive and starting with zero like

- component1 => drawing order: 0
- component2 => drawing order: 1
- component3 => drawing order: 2
- component4 => drawing order: 3

?

Answer (score 5):

It can be anything

`This value can be any integer. Components in the GameComponentCollection are drawn in ascending order based on their DrawOrder.`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.draworder.aspx